# DataTable 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<CheckBoxProps & RefAttributes<any>>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typeerror, react-data-table-component

I am using `DataTable` from `react-data-table-component` and I am trying to apply my custom checkbox styling following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72409272/react-data-table-component-how-to-style-checkbox-large-checkboxes-to-small)

What I tried, I set the `DataTable` property `selectableRowsComponent` as below

My `Checkbox` code

```
type CheckBoxProps = {
  onClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> | undefined
}

const Checkbox = React.forwardRef<any, CheckBoxProps>(({onClick, ...rest}, ref) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="form-check pb-5" style={{backgroundColor: ''}}>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          className="form-check-input"
          style={{height: '20px', width: '20px'}}
          ref={ref}
          onClick={onClick}
          {...rest}
        />
        <label className="form-check-label" id="booty-check"/>
      </div>
    </>
  )
})
```

My `DataTable` code

```
<DataTable
  ....
  selectableRows
  selectableRowsComponent={Checkbox}
  ....
/>
```

I am getting a type error on the line `selectableRowsComponent={Checkbox}`

```
TS2322: Type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<CheckBoxProps & RefAttributes<any>>' is not assignable to 
type 'ReactNode'.  types.d.ts(100, 5): The expected type comes from property 'selectableRowsComponent' 
which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TableProps<T>'
```

I also tried passing the `Checkbox` to property `selectableRowsComponent` as below (I know the documentation says not to do the below, but just as a test)

```
<DataTable
  ....
  selectableRows
  selectableRowsComponent={<Checkbox onClick={onClickHandler}/>}
  ....
/>
```

The error goes away, but on run time I get the error

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
    at createFiberFromTypeAndProps (http://localhost:3012/static/js/bundle.js:171839:21)
    at createFiberFromElement (http://localhost:3012/static/js/bundle.js:171860:19)
    at reconcileSingleElement (http://localhost:3012/static/js/bundle.js:161016:27)
    at reconcileChildFibers (http://localhost:3012/static/js/bundle.js:161066:39)
    at reconcileChildren (http://localhost:3012/static/js/bundle.js:164782:32)
    at updateFunctionComponent (http://localhost:3012/static/js/bundle.js:165153:7)
    at updateSimpleMemoComponent (http://localhost:3012/static/js/bundle.js:164993:14)
    at updateMemoComponent (http://localhost:3012/static/js/bundle.js:164882:18)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3012/static/js/bundle.js:166925:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3012/static/js/bundle.js:151231:18)
```

For now what I did to fix the error and be able to continue is to ignore the error as below (but ofcourse this is not a permanent solution)

```
<DataTable
  ....
  selectableRows
  // @ts-ignore
  selectableRowsComponent={Checkbox}
  ....
/>
```

I am using

- react^18.0.0
- react-data-table-component^7.5.3
- typescript^4.6.3